# Authentication using encryption Vs decryption

Tags: authentication, encryption

Which is better during authentication of user login password

Using the encryption algorithm where you encrypt the user entered password and compare it with the stored encrypted user password

Or

Using the decryption algorithm where you decrypt the stored user encrypted password and compare it with the user entered password

Any inputs would be appreciated

Comment: passwords shouldn't be encrypted, they should be *hashed*. The plaintext password should never be know. It's a one direction process -- does the given text **when hashed** equal the saved password hash in the database? Therefore the original database stored hashed text is never remembered.

Comment: @Martin then how is it validated

Comment: I think you need to read up on some basic cryptographic and internet security texts before you actually try and do anything. It will help you a lot. #

Comment: [Please start here](https://gcn.com/articles/2013/12/02/hashing-vs-encryption.aspx)

Comment: @psaraj12 you should compare password hashes (something like your case 1, but using slow salted hash instead of encryption), see https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/

Comment: See [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) from informationSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For allowing access, passwords should be **hashed** *not* encrypted.

The plaintext password should never be stored on any system. Only the generated *hash of that password* should be stored.

A Hash is a **one way encryption** that turns a password string into a garbled unique reference string.

An Encrypted cyphertext is one of these strings that can be converted back to being a plaintext string.

But you don't need to know the password, you only need to know it's the **same** - when the login occurs; the username/email or whatever is used to select the database row. The *hashed password* is grabbed and brought back and then the plaintext password given at login is *hashed in just the same way*. If the results are **identical** then the password string is the same as the original so the user can log on.

---

It's like cooking a cake.

You have a list of ingredients - but these are secret, you must not share these with anyone. So you have a cake you made with these ingredients in the cupboard. The *cake* is the `hash` (er, hashcake?), the *ingredients* are the `password`.

So when someone else tries to make your cake, they use their ingredients and it will make a different cake you don't know what their ingredients are,  but once it's cooked (300ms) it will be a different cake so the Desert Chef in the kitchen knows it's not *you*.  Only an idiot would put this much garlic in a *cake*.

Comment: I got your point so hash is the way to go and decryption is a no no , thanks

Comment: Does this answer hold good even if I have access to the stored password in hashed form

Comment: @psaraj12 **yes**. Hashed form is the *only* form you should have access to passwords in.